# MS Access SQL query a table and remove duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have reviewed several posts here and can't find the answer, but it may be that the problem and answer are a bit above my pay grade.

I have an MSAccess Table with two ID fields (ID1 and ID2), and many other columns.

I want to query (SELECT statement) the table and need two things to happen. Not sure if the order matters. I want the query to return all columns from the table.

- No duplicates for ID1, and I simply don't care which record(s) gets thrown away.
- No duplicates for ID2, and I want to keep the record where the Date field in the table is earlier than the other values for records with the same ID2 value.

Just can't figure out how to do this with an SQL Select statement.

Example Data - assume DateFld is ASC from top to bottom

```
ID1    ID2    DateFld    ...
1      24
1      24
2      23
3      98
4      23
4      23
5      98
6      72
```

Keep rows 1, 3, 4, 8

No indices, as this table was created from a make table query; but I can add them. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  That said, I suspect you cannot easily do what you want in MS Access, unless your data has other constraints that you haven't described.

Comment: Yes, need examples. If data is like: `1 1`, `2 1` - one of these must be eliminated because ID2 is duplicated? Exactly what do you mean by "duplicate" - all fields are same value? Are ID1 and ID2 a unique compound index? Is there a unique identifier such as autonumber?

Comment: In your sample data for each ID1 there is only 1 ID2, although in more than 1 rows. Is this a coincidence or does this rule apply to your table? Also could there be duplicate DateFlds for each ID2?

Comment: ID2 (and DateFld) will be the same for all unique values of ID1; as shown above for ID2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample data you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tablename AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tablename
  WHERE ID2 = t.ID2 AND DateFld < t.DateFld
)
```

Results:

```
ID1 ID2 DateFld
1   24  ...
2   23  ...
3   98  ...
6   72  ...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
  ID1, 
  ID2, 
  [allOtherColumns]
FROM(
  SELECT 
      ID1, 
      ID2, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID1 ORDER BY ID1) AS ID1Selector, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID2 ORDER BY DateValue ASC) AS ID2Selector,
      [allOtherColumns)
  FROM tbl) AS InnerQry
WHERE ID1Selector=1 AND ID2Selector=1
```

Note, this is SQL Server code that *might* work in Access. I don't have a lot of experience with Access, but I know SQL. In SQL, the ROW_NUMBER() window function will split ID1 by unique ID1s so the first ID1 it comes across will be the only one it selects, and the ID2Selector will give the Row Number 1 to the earliest date value it comes across within each individual ID2.

There might be a more efficient way to do it, but that is how I always do it in SQL.

Comment: Thanks Tyler H but row_number() not supported in Access.